"ddev start" won't work "Failed waiting for web/db containers to become ready"
I followed the instructions here and here to spin up a new drupal instance. After running
composer create-project drupal/recommended-project:10.3.1 "PaleFire"

Everything seemed to run fine. Then I run ddev config.
worryword@WorryWord:~/Development/websites/PaleFire$ ddev config
Creating a new DDEV project config in the current directory (/home/worryword/Development/websites/PaleFire) 
Once completed, your configuration will be written to /home/worryword/Development/websites/PaleFire/.ddev/config.yaml
 
Project name (PaleFire): 

The docroot is the directory from which your site is served.
This is a relative path from your project root at /home/worryword/Development/websites/PaleFire 
You may leave this value blank if your site files are in the project root 
Docroot Location (web): 
Found a drupal codebase at /home/worryword/Development/websites/PaleFire/web. 
Project Type [backdrop, cakephp, craftcms, django4, drupal, drupal6, drupal7, laravel, magento, magento2, php, python, shopware6, silverstripe, typo3, wordpress] (drupal): 
No settings.php file exists, creating one 
Configuration complete. You may now run 'ddev start'. 
worryword@WorryWord:~/Development/websites/PaleFire$ ddev start
Starting PaleFire... 
Building project images... 
.Project images built in 1s. 
 Container ddev-PaleFire-db  Created 
 Container ddev-PaleFire-web  Created 
 Container ddev-PaleFire-web  Started 
 Container ddev-PaleFire-db  Started 
Waiting for containers to become ready: [web db] 
Failed waiting for web/db containers to become ready: db container failed: log=, err=ddev-PaleFire-db container exited, more info with [
    ddev logs -s db
    docker logs ddev-PaleFire-db
    docker inspect --format "{{ json .State.Health }}" ddev-PaleFire-db | docker run -i --rm ddev/ddev-utilities jq -r
] 

As you can see, config worked fine, but ddev start fails.
I followed the instructions here to trouble shoot this.
worryword@WorryWord:~/Development/websites/PaleFire$ docker inspect --format "{{json .State.Health }}" ddev-PaleFire-web | jq
{
  "Status": "healthy",
  "FailingStreak": 0,
  "Log": [
    {
      "Start": "2024-07-19T23:37:19.683303974-04:00",
      "End": "2024-07-19T23:37:20.281341934-04:00",
      "ExitCode": 1,
      "Output": "/var/www/html:OK mailpit:FAILED phpstatus:FAILED "
    },
    {
      "Start": "2024-07-19T23:37:21.296713665-04:00",
      "End": "2024-07-19T23:37:21.956626452-04:00",
      "ExitCode": 0,
      "Output": "/var/www/html:OK mailpit:OK phpstatus:OK "
    },
    {
      "Start": "2024-07-19T23:37:22.979103375-04:00",
      "End": "2024-07-19T23:38:22.652750191-04:00",
      "ExitCode": 0,
      "Output": "container was previously healthy, so sleeping 59 seconds before continuing healthcheck... /var/www/html:OK mailpit:OK phpstatus:OK "
    },
    {
      "Start": "2024-07-19T23:38:23.666710184-04:00",
      "End": "2024-07-19T23:39:23.31907578-04:00",
      "ExitCode": 0,
      "Output": "container was previously healthy, so sleeping 59 seconds before continuing healthcheck... /var/www/html:OK mailpit:OK phpstatus:OK "
    },
    {
      "Start": "2024-07-19T23:39:24.341985581-04:00",
      "End": "2024-07-19T23:40:23.992738936-04:00",
      "ExitCode": 0,
      "Output": "container was previously healthy, so sleeping 59 seconds before continuing healthcheck... /var/www/html:OK mailpit:OK phpstatus:OK "
    }
  ]
}

So it says my image is healthy right? Well if I follow the suggestion in the error message I get a different answer:
worryword@WorryWord:~/Development/websites/PaleFire$ docker inspect --format "{{ json .State.Health }}" ddev-PaleFire-db | docker run -i --rm ddev/ddev-utilities jq -r
{
  "Status": "unhealthy",
  "FailingStreak": 0,
  "Log": []
}

So what is going on here?
ddev version is 1.23.3 and drupal version is 10.3.1

You need to ask DDEV/server questions on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ddev

Steps I took to fix this:

Restart computer
run "composer require drush/drush"
run "ddev drush cr"

Now it works.

Thanks for sharing your solution. It IS a bit concise though, care to elaborate?
